# how to make actions global in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js

I need to have global actions doLogin `{{ action "doLogin" }}` that can be accessible from all of my handlebar templates

Is there a way to achieve this or probably I have to create global controllers on my ember-cli app?

Comment: Whats is your use case for this? It is common to create component and use that.

Comment: I'm new with ember, so I just need to have doLogin as actions that can be call on every handlebar template without define it on each of my controllers.
I dont want to use component because I dont want to write component template and just want doLogin callable from anywhere
Is this thing only achievable with ember component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very simple, although it is far from optimal way. To put your action literally in every controller, you can reopen it in initializer and write it in there. You just have to create file `app/initializers/controller-login.js` with `ember generate initializer controller-login`: and put there something like this:

```
//app/initializers/controller-login.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize() {
  Ember.Controller.reopen({
    actions: {
      doLogin() {
        // ...
      }
    }
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'controller-login',
  initialize,
};
```

Then in your template you can do `<button {{action "doLogin"}}>do login</button>` as you wanted.

That being said I would strongly suggest creating component for that instead.
You can generete one with `ember g component login-button` and put there

```
//components/login-button.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({    
  actions: {
    login() {
     // ...
    }
  }
});
```

It will also generate template for you:

```
//templates/components/login-button.hbs
<button {{action 'login'}}>Login</button>
```

And finally you will be able to use this everywhere in your website.

```
//templates/*.hbs
<div>
    for login click here: {{login-button}}
</div>
```

Comment: I never really thought to use initializers to reopen classes and such, good suggestion. Although it could be an awkward location for a commonly used action

Comment: @ABot If you are looking that what you are asking for, then [`reopen`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/) is what you are asking for. But you shouldn't do this. You can use a login button as suggested in this answer and put that login button at your [`application.hbs`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/tutorial/routes-and-templates/#toc_adding-a-banner-with-navigation). So it will render at every page of your application.